# Striding in numpy and pytorch, How force writing to an array or "input tensor and the written-to tensor refer to a single memory location"?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, sum

Experimenting with both numpy arrays and pytorch tensors I have came across a difference in an attempt to "do black magic" related to time series that rely on previous time steps

A key feature of the numpy-esque libraries is that they often don't copy data but manipulate it in different views. one of the most interesting tools to do that in numpy is using stride_tricks's functions.

As a simpler problem I was trying to make an "inplace cumsum" but i stumbled upon the fact that numpy doesn't error out and a seemingly equivalent code of pytorch.
I don't really need an in place cumsum implementation but rather inplace broadcasting operation that will use inbroadcast-calculated data.

So my questions are; How can I force pytorch to allow the sum?; How can I make numpy not make a copy of my data and sum over it?

```
import numpy as np
# array = np.arange(6.)
array = np.arange(6.).reshape(2,3) + 3
# array([[3., 4., 5.],
#       [6., 7., 8.]])
s = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(array, shape=(1,3)) # array([[3., 4., 5.]])
array += s
array
# array([[ 6.,  8., 10.],
#        [ 9., 11., 13.]])
```

```
import torch
t = torch.arange(6.).reshape(2,3) + 3
# tensor([[3., 4., 5.],
        # [6., 7., 8.]])
s = t.as_strided(size=(1,3),stride=(1,1)) # tensor([[3., 4., 5.]])
t += s
t
# RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
#       3 # tensor([[3., 4., 5.],
#       4         # [6., 7., 8.]])
#       5 s = t.as_strided(size=(1,3),stride=(1,1)) # tensor([[3., 4., 5.]])
# ----> 6 t += s
#       7 t

# RuntimeError: unsupported operation: some elements of the input tensor and the written-to tensor refer to a single memory location. Please clone() the tensor before performing the operation.
```

Desired:

```py
#sum the first row to itself inplace
#sum the 2nd row with the inplace modified 1st row
array([[6., 8., 10.],
      [12., 15., 18.]])
```

Comment: `+=` is buffered. `np.add.at` is an unbuffered version. I don't know how it would work with this strided view.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [129]: arr=np.arange(3,9).reshape(2,3);
In [130]: s=arr[None,0]  # or the strided

In [131]: np.add.at(arr,((0,1,1),slice(None)),s)

In [132]: arr
Out[132]: 
array([[ 6,  8, 10],
       [12, 15, 18]])

In [133]: s
Out[133]: array([[ 6,  8, 10]])
```

`add.at` is most used to handled duplicated indices.

While the numbers match, I'm not sure it's doing your cumsum.

Comment: I have also seen the 'at' feature it indeed doesn't sum inplace as i want but can reproduce sum like behavior that is similar given you want a complex form of summation over your data. sadly i believe it's not what i am looking for because i want to sum into zeroed out data and then reuse it in "later" iteration of the broadcast creating a "time" dependency between entries. with the at notation i'll just add 0s as it used the original data rather than the "newly calculated" indecies. this in essence will allow for loops with assignments given broadcasting syntax.

Comment: It's entirely possible that `add.at` buffers the `s` argument.  So even if it iterates over the indices, the original `s` is used each time.